# How to reset week counter on the new-year day in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, week-number

As you know, week attribute of pandas dt objects are ISO weeks. Instead, I want to assign the rows in my data a week number that is 1 for the first days of January and becomes 2 on the first Monday that is not on Jan 1st. Similarly, I don't want to have week 1 in December. It should increase the week number instead of resetting it. Here is normal behaviour:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range(start = '12/27/2019', end = '1/2/2020')})
df["Week_day"] = df.Date.dt.weekday
df["Week"] = df.Date.dt.week
df

        Date  Week  Week_day
0 2019-12-27    52         4
1 2019-12-28    52         5
2 2019-12-29    52         6
3 2019-12-30     1         0
4 2019-12-31     1         1
5 2020-01-01     1         2
6 2020-01-02     1         3
```

And this is what I want:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range(start = '12/27/2019', end = '1/2/2020'),
                   "Week":[52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 1, 1]})
df2["Week_day"] = df2.Date.dt.weekday
df2

        Date  Week  Week_day
0 2019-12-27    52         4
1 2019-12-28    52         5
2 2019-12-29    52         6
3 2019-12-30    53         0
4 2019-12-31    53         1
5 2020-01-01     1         2
6 2020-01-02     1         3
```

Can I do this with pandas methods or should I write my own function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should do

```
df.Date.dt.strftime('%W').astype(int)+1
Out[108]: 
0    52
1    52
2    52
3    53
4    53
5     1
6     1
Name: Date, dtype: int32
```